# Azure Logic App HTTP action authorization fails

Tags: azure, http, azure-logic-apps

So I'm trying to set some custom meta-data for Blobs inside a Logic App. Unfortunately there's currently no Action which is capable of setting custom data on blobs.

So as a workaround I try to set the meta-data by using the REST API and configured the following Action (SharedKey is in Format StorageAccountName:AccessKey1):

[image: Configuration of HTTP Action to set meta-data]

So for the x-ms-date header I use the expression utcNow() but that doesn't seem to do the job as I get the following error message:

"x-ms-date": "2018-09-04T14:20:01.1767834Z"

> `AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   RequestId:0c5c817f-101e-00b5-7c5a-44ca3c000000
>   Time:2018-09-04T14:20:01.2206329ZThe Date header in the request is incorrect.

Strangely enough, besides the x-ms-date Header also the Date header already seems to be included automatically in the correct format:

[image: Output of the finished action]

So does anybody see an error here (wrong utc-date Expression for example)? Maybe it's not even the wrong x-ms-date header and I'm on the wrong track..

Answer (score 0):

I had a silimar issue and figured out how to Authenticate. Maybe you can use it for your solution:

Here is what worked for me:

1. Enabled "Managed Identity" on the Logic App.
2. Added Storage-Queue-Contributor permissions on the storage queue.
3. Used `utcnow('R')` to get this date format ("Tue, 08 Sep 2020 12:03:08
   GMT") for `x-ms-date` HTTP header (no doc from MS about this).
4. Inserted JSON data inside

   ```xml
   <QueueMessage> 
       <MessageText>
       {
         "car": "Audi",
         "year": 1983
       }
      </MessageText>  
   </QueueMessage>
   ```

Final result in Logic App designer:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Issue could be related to the format of the final value that Authorization header is getting.

Take a look at [this post on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/54e5b206-aac8-4ed5-b82c-b0859e5f22f0/storage-restapi-list-containers-quotthe-date-header-in-the-request-is-incorrectquot?forum=windowsazuredata)

Comment: Have you figured it out?