# Using the Logic App HTTP connector, I get "BadGateway. Http request failed as there is an error getting AD OAuth token", when trying to call Graph API

Tags: http, oauth, access-token

I am trying to make an API call to Microsoft Graph using the Microsoft Logic App HTTP connector. The call fails with the error:
"BadGateway. Http request failed as there is an error getting AD OAuth token: 'Failed to extract error details from response content ''.'.".

I have been trying many things including being able to run the call successfully via Postman. I have decrypted the Postman token with jwt.ms and verified certain values such as:

```
"aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
"iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{{tenantId}}/",
```

I went through stacks of Google searches, and as for Stack Exchange, these are the closest matching posts that I could find.

[Http request failed as there is an error getting AD OAuth token: 'AADSTS50001: The application named https://management.azure.windows.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615666/http-request-failed-as-there-is-an-error-getting-ad-oauth-token-aadsts50001-t)

- In this case the audience paramater was wrong, and in my case I have tried many, and not really sure anymore which is the correct one, even though none of them worked for me when tested.

[Azure Logic App HTTP action authorization fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177110/azure-logic-app-http-action-authorization-fails)

- The post deals with a shared key use case. My current requirement for this project is to use OAuth.

[Secure access and data in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#azure-active-directory-oauth-authentication)

I have tried the following for "Authority":

```
"authority": "https://sts.windows.net/{{tenantId}}/"
"authority": "HTTPS://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/"
"authority": "HTTPS://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
```

[This is the screen that shows the HTTP connector inside the logic app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejxUD.png)

[This is the same connector at runtime.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUqBr.png)

[This is the raw HTML that the HTTP connector generates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzuLd.png)

Hoping someone can spot where I am going wrong.

Comment: Did you get any solution? Have you checked with permissions?

Comment: No not yet. Yes I have checked the permissions. Also, I am able to get it to work in Postman, but unable to see the final raw code sent by Postman.

Comment: Just to update that this remains unresolved. Assistance would be sincerely appreciated.